# How to give filename based on block number

Tags: python, file-writing, data-extraction

I have data file which contains `lat`, `lon` and some parameters. `Lat` & `lon` values are repeated for different pressure levels. I want to write out lat, lon & parameters of different pressure levels in different files and name them based on iteration or block number.

I don't have pressure level to identify end of pressure level so I identify end of pressure level by identifying end of lat, lon block using `line.strip()` and break, Is there any other way to identify repetition of lat and lon and write the data after that into different files. I'm having 50 such data files and in every file lat and lon's are different so I want to identify end of pressure level based on repetition of lat and lon and write data to a file.

```
import io
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('./d_airsdata_0.csv')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    with open(file_name) as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            with io.open("file_" + str(line) + ".dat",'w') as f:
                if line.strip():
                    if '24.16 100.00' in line :
                        break
        for line in input_data:
            if line.strip() == '40.71  99.30':
                break
            print(line)
            f.write(str(line))
            f.close()
```

I expect to write out data of different pressure levels into different files and name them according to iteration number or block number.

Comment: Have you tried `enumerate`? i.e. `for i, file_name in enumerate(list_of_files)`

Comment: @MikeSperry It's not duplicate of that question. I tried methods mentioned in that question but didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I think perhaps the title of your question is way confused me with respect to what you are really trying to do. Maybe change "iteration" to "block number" in the title to avoid the confusion?

Comment: *"I don't have pressure level to identify end of pressure level so I identify end of pressure level by identifying end of lat, lon block..."* That's very unclear, please just show us your input file format already.